Connected Metric Spaces: Strategies
I am not really sure if my ideas in this topic are correct. Can anyone help me?

Finding the connected components of a metric space $X$.

Suppose there are two connected components $C_1, C_2$ of $X$. In this case, I have to prove that each component is connected, non-empty, open and closed in $X$, and that:

$C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$
$C_1 \cup C_2 = X$

And in case there are more than 2, or infinitely many, what do I need to prove?

Proving that a subset $S \subset X$ is a connected component.

As far as I know, there's no need now for a connected component to be an open set. Then, what do I need to prove exactly, appart from connectedness of $S$? I suppose that there's no other superset $T\supset S$ which is connected, but how?

Not every connected component is a path-connected component, and not every path-connected component is a connected component.

For the second statement, are there any well-known examples?

Just a comment: if you manage to prove that $C_1 \cap C_2 = \varnothing$ and $C_1 \cup C_2 = X$, then you do not need to show that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are open and closed. Open will imply closed, and vice versa, since you already know that they are complement in $X$.

Any connected component is closed.  If there are infinitely many components, it's not guaranteed that each of them is open.  There are non-discrete spaces whose every connected component consists of a point ( like the Cantor set).
